# Can I run a fuse block on different power supplies connected to the same terminals, depending on mobile vs. AC power availability?

Tags: safety, wiring, dual-supply

I am wiring a trailer lighting system and I want to be able to run off AC power when parked at home, but run on a AGM deep cycle battery when AC power is not available. I've attached a drawing of the proposed setup and am really just looking to know if this would be considered a safe setup.
Keep in mind, they would not be operational at the same time.

- When plugged in at home on an inlet plug with a built-in splitter, the lights would run off AC power through the converter, but also run the on-board charger to recharge the battery. The isolator switch on the positive cable on the battery side would be set to 'Off.'
- When mobile, the lights would run off the battery side, isolator switch on. Nothing would be plugged in on the AC side to power the converter so no juice coming in on the other end.
- Each side would never be in use simultaneously, but they would both be permanently attached to the positive and negative terminals on the fuse block.

Obviously, there would be concerns if both sides are supplying power at the same time but I'm more worried about any bleed over from one side to the other.

Would I want to add an isolator switch to the negative wire on the battery side?

Would I want an isolator switch on the positive feed on the converter side to break the circuit there, too?

Any concerns with attaching both sides to the same fuse block terminals?

Please excuse the crude drawing. Newb to electrical engineering. TIA for any help.[image]

Comment: Correction on the drawing: the negative coming from the battery flows through the low voltage cutoff before connecting to the fuse block.